# click is not woking on anchor tag in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$("#downloadlink").attr("href", url);
$("#downloadlink").click();

<a href="" id="downloadlink" target="_blank" download></a>
```

I am trying to change anchor tag href value with a download link and then clicking on it by using jquery but its not working

Comment: wrap those jquery statements in a `$(document).ready( function() {})`

Comment: To trigger a download you need to use the native `click()` method: `$('#downloadlink')[0].click()`

Answer (score 0):

What about this one?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#downloadlink").css({"text-decoration": "underline", "color":"blue","cursor":"pointer"});
  
    $("#downloadlink").click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      window.location.href = "file:///Users/buraq-mac/Downloads/back@2x.png";
  });
});
```